# ruby on rails No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pythonhowto"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**I'm getting a routing error when I browse to my pythonhowto/new page.error is No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pythonhowto"}**

*my controller*

```
class PythonhowtoController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @pythonhowto = Post.all
   end
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end
def new
    @post = Post.new
  end   
  def create
  end
```

*my pythonhowto/new is*

```
<%= form_for(@post, :url =>{:action=>"show", :controller=>"pythonhowto"}) do |f| %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
R::Application.routes.draw do
```

resources :pythonhowto

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you likely should not be `post`ing to a `show` method. To fix your current problem however, you need to do `form_for(..., :url => your_route_path_helper)`. You can find this by doing `rake routes`. Once you find your route path helper name, you can simply use `helper_name_path` or `helper_name_url`, which both accept query parameter functions if you need to pass those.

Comment: Hi, IT Ninja, this is unrelated to the answer, sorry for the intrusion. You shouldn't have approved http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4056938. The white space there was carefully tabulated by the author for better visual appearance, and the edit broke that. Thanks. :)